# Eighties sci-fi tv show, trying to remember

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship

I'm trying to remember a sci-fi tv show from early eighties I believe.
It was about people/soldiers flying in planes or spacecraft, flying through gorges with bridges (or some kind). Not sure if that was the enemy. The bridges or spans were glowing in several colors. The setting is very dark and misty and I believe it was not an American series. It looked very post apocalyptic.

Comment: The show was about people flying though bridges? That seems odd. Was that a single scene or the entire premise?

Comment: Didn't realize "Barnstorming" was made into a TV show ;) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwFos9dcagA

Comment: Only thing I can think of was a film called [Slipstream (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(1989_film)). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ut_CUdr-gfI  No bridges tough.

Comment: Is it possible this was part of the *Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future) series? They did have some flying sequences through gorges with bridges. It was part of how the lightgun/ship toy worked.

Comment: Could it be "Space above and beyond"? It had some scenes like that, but it was from the 90s.